# Subtracting two plots in matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, subtraction

I have two plots which I would like to subtract, but I encounter some errors. My code looks like this:

In general:

```
for dataset in [Bxfft]:
    dataset = np.asarray(dataset)
    freqs, psd = signal.welch(dataset, fs=52718/300, window='hamming', nperseg=16384, scaling='spectrum')
    plt.semilogy(freqs[5:4600], psd[5:4600]/dataset.size**0, color='r', label='Bx')

    x = freqs[5:361]
    y = psd[5:361]
    x2 = freqs[5:4600]
    y2 = psd[5:4600]
```

What I try to accomplish is to subtract `x2 - x` and `y2 - y`. I tried to do this two ways, but I got some errors:

1. `o = x-x2[:,:361]
   o2 = y-y2[:,:361]
   plt.semilogy(o, o2 / dataset.size ** 0, color='r', label='Bx')`

And the error looks like this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "S:/Doktorat/Python/Data/Dekomp/substraction.py", line 57, in 
>       o = x-x2[:,:4800] IndexError: too many indices for array

2. `o = x2-x
   o2 = y2-y
   plt.semilogy(o, o2 / dataset.size ** 0, color='r', label='Bx')`

And the error looks like this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "S:/Doktorat/Python/Data/Dekomp/substraction.py", line 57, in 
>       o = x2-x ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4595,) (356,)

Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Its Simple Matrix Problem. As Basic Matrix Operations like subtraction and addition can only be performed when both the matrices have same dimensions, which in your case is not.
That's why the error is there.
You need to change your larger matrix to a lower dimension in order to subtract the two.

Answer (score 1):

Your `x`, `x2`, `y`, `y2` arrays seem to be 1 dimensional,

So your first intuition was correct but you will have to make a small correction in the slice of array your are substracting:

```
o = x-x2[:356] # 361-5 = 356
o2 = y-y2[:356]
```

And a working example of this would be:

```
import numpy as np

freqs = np.random.rand(4600)
psd = np.random.rand(4600)

x = freqs[5:361]
y = psd[5:361]
x2 = freqs[5:4600]
y2 = psd[5:4600]

o = x-x2[:356]
o2 = y-y2[:356]
```

**Edit plot example:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

freqs = np.random.rand(4600)
psd = np.random.rand(4600)

x = freqs[5:361]
y = psd[5:361]
x2 = freqs[5:4600]
y2 = psd[5:4600]

o = abs(x-x2[1:357])
o2 = abs(y-y2[1:357])

plt.semilogy(o, o2, '*',color='r', label='Bx')

plt.show()
```

**Array slicing explanation**

According to your code you have 2 arrays (`freq` and `psd`), each one is 1 dimensional and contains at least 4600 values.

When you do

```
x = freqs[5:361]
x = psd[5:361]
```

You are extracting all values from the 5 position to the 361th position, `x` and `y` therefore contain 356 values each.

When you do :
    x2 = freqs[5:4600]
    y2 = psd[5:4600]

You are extracting all values from the 5 position (the same as before) to the 4600th position, `x2` and `y2` therefore contain 3595 values each

Later you try to subtract `x2` and `x` first by using `x2[:,:361]` which means you are considering `x2` to be a 2d array when in fact it is 1d which results in an error.

Then you try doing `o = x2-x` but as `x` contains 356 values and `x2` contains 3595 values python doesn't know what to do.

If for example you wanted to subtract the first 3 values to the following 3 ones in a very simple example you would do the following:

```
freq = np.array([3,3,3,2,2,2])
x1 = freq[0:3] # x1 =  array([3, 3, 3])
x2 = freq[3:6] # x2 =  array([2, 2, 2])

result = x1 - x2 # result = array([1, 1, 1])
```

Comment: Well subtraction worked, but plot is empty, I get this error:
UserWarning: Data has no positive values, and therefore cannot be log-scaled.
  "Data has no positive values, and therefore cannot be "

Comment: The problem is I'm not sure what values you want to plot, right now the example subtracts each value of the array to itself resulting in an array of zeros which can not be represented in a Log plot.